# Suppose there are 1000 elements, we randomly pick two sets of 50 elements. What's the expectation of number of elements in intersection

Tags: probability, combinatorics, expected-value

I'm able to write the distribution of the number of elements in the intersection. But is there any faster way to get their average/expectation?

Comment: Suggestion: Find the probability that a designated element is in the intersection, then apply linearity of expectation.

Comment: 5% of the elements of master set are in each subset.  If the subsets are chosen independently of one another, the probability that a given element is in both subsets?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can do it by linearity of expectation.

For each element $x$ the probability $x$ is in the intersection is simply the probability it is in both sets, which is $\big(\frac{50}{1000}\big)^2$.

Therefore the expected number of such elements is $1000\times \big(\frac{50}{1000}\big)^2=2.5$.

Answer (score 0):

Probability to get one element in intersection is $ [\binom{50}{1}*\binom{950}{49}] /\binom{1000}{50}$

Similarly for two elements it will be $ [\binom{50}{2}*\binom{950}{48}] /\binom{1000}{50}$

> But is there any faster way to get their average/expectation?

If we can code it, that would be pretty fast. For a logic that is simpler and faster, I would welcome answers.

I have used python 3.5 for the code.

```
from math import factorial
import numpy as np

def nCr(n,r):
    # calculate the N choose r ways.
    f = factorial
    return f(n)/(f(r)*f(n-r))


def ExpectedElements(initialDraws, totalElements):
    # 

    sampleSpacesize = initialDraws

    remElements = totalElements - initialDraws
    listExpectation = [] # an emppty list that stores P(x)*X

    for i in range(1, sampleSpacesize + 1):
    # Expected number of elements = sum(probability of getting that no. of 
    # elements*number of elements)

        listExpectation.append(i*(nCr(sampleSpacesize, i)*nCr(remElements, 
             initialDraws - i)/nCr(totalElements, initialDraws)))


    listExpectation = np.array(listExpectation)   
    print(listExpectation.sum())
    print(listExpectation[0])
    return(listExpectation.sum())



ExpectedElements(50, 1000)  
ExpectedElements(100, 1000)       
ExpectedElements(200, 1000)             
ExpectedElements(500, 1000)
```